# How to set array or multiples var inside jquery .html() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

I've got a array with content [a,b,c] and I need to put it inside a .html()

and my original place its 3  child
When i put it directly - this way:

```
$('#listProducts div ul li').html(newElements); (not esactly this code, but I short it)
```

whats happens (return like this [abc]):

```
<div id=listProducts>
<ul>
  <li>A,B,C</li>
  <li>A,B,C</li>
  <li>A,B,C</li>
</ul></div>
```

result i want:

```
<div id=listProducts>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul></div>
```

I tried this:

```
$('#listProducts ul li ul li div').html(function(newElements){

for(let i = 0; i < newElements.length; i++){ 
 newElements[i];
}

});
```

but i research about functions inside .html() and it seems only accept index parameters.

i think about something like

```
 $().html(newElements[0],newElements[1],newElements[2]) or
separe in 3 variables  $().html(element1,newElements2,newElements3) // but i guess its not possible with .html()
```

Is there a way to do that?
Ps: I cant change the HTML, and i cant just send directly someting like `<li> + newElements[i];` because its atached with backend parameters uniques with every div, ul, etc.

Its my first question at SO, and english is not my first language. So if a make any mistake, please advice me and I'll change. Thank you so much!!

Edit1:

testing:

```
.html(function(i) {
  return arr[i];
});
```

FULL CODE:

```js
const arr = $('#listProducts ul li ul li div a').get().sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.getAttribute('href') > b.getAttribute('href') ? 1 : -1;
}).map(function(el) {
  return $(el).clone(true)[0];
});


$('#listProducts ul li ul li div').html(function(i) {
  return arr[i];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="listProducts" class="listagem borda-alpha ">
    <ul data-produtos-linha="3">
      <li class="listagem-linha ">
        <ul class="">
          <li class="span4">
            <div class="listagem-item">
              <a href="https://test.com/2-test" class="produto-sobrepor" title="TEST 2">2TH ELEMENT</a>
              <div class="another 1">another div 1</div>
              <div class="another 2">another div 2</div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="span4">
            <div class="listagem-item">
              <a href="https://test.com/3-test" class="produto-sobrepor" title="TEST 3">3RD ELEMENT</a>
              <div class="another 1">another div 1</div>
              <div class="another 2">another div 2</div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="span4">
            <div class="listagem-item">
              <a href="https://test.com/1-test" class="produto-sobrepor" title="TEST 1">1st ELEMENT</a>
              <div class="another 1">another div 1</div>
              <div class="another 2">another div 2</div>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

expected:

```html
 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>
      <div id="listProducts" class="listagem borda-alpha ">
        <ul data-produtos-linha="3">
          <li class="listagem-linha ">
            <ul class="">
              <li class="span4">
                <div class="listagem-item">
                  <a href="https://test.com/1-test" class="produto-sobrepor" title="TEST 1">1st ELEMENT</a>
                  <div class="another 1">another div 1</div>
                  <div class="another 2">another div 2</div>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li class="span4">
                <div class="listagem-item">
                  <a href="https://test.com/2-test" class="produto-sobrepor" title="TEST 2">2ND ELEMENT</a>
                  <div class="another 1">another div 1</div>
                  <div class="another 2">another div 2</div>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li class="span4">
                <div class="listagem-item">
                  <a href="https://test.com/3-test" class="produto-sobrepor" title="TEST 3">3RD ELEMENT</a>
                  <div class="another 1">another div 1</div>
                  <div class="another 2">another div 2</div>
                </div>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

ADD:

- The .get().sort is to sort the results alphabetically, according to the URL and is working fine.
- "another div 1" and "another div 2" are not the same as those "another div 1" and "another div 2" on the other li.
- There are much more than 3 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<li>` items are already in the `<ul>`, you can pass a function into `.html()` and use the index `i` it gives to access the content you want to place into each `<li>` like so:

```js
const arr = ['A','B','C'];
$("#listProducts ul li").html(function(i) {
  return arr[i];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=listProducts>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If the `<li>`s aren't already inside your `<ul>` you can map your `arr` to a list of elements, and then use `.html()` to add these elements to the `<ul>`:

```js
const arr = ['A','B','C'];
$("#listProducts ul").html($.map(arr, function(text) {
  return $('<li>', {text});
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=listProducts>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

You can get all the `<li>` and sort these by the anchor tags `href` attribute. You can then use `.append()` to append the sorted elements to your DOM. The purpose of using `.append()` rather than `.html()` is that `.append()` will insert the elements into the DOM, thus removing the old element and adding the new one (so no need to `.clone()`)

```js
const arr = $('#listProducts ul li ul li').get().sort(function(a, b) {
  const anchorA = $("a", a);
  const anchorB = $("a", b);
  return anchorA.attr('href') > anchorB.attr('href') ? 1 : -1;
});
$('#listProducts ul li ul').append(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="listProducts" class="listagem borda-alpha ">
    <ul data-produtos-linha="3">
      <li class="listagem-linha ">
        <ul class="">
          <li class="span4">
            <div class="listagem-item">
              <a href="https://test.com/2-test" class="produto-sobrepor" title="TEST 2">2TH ELEMENT</a>
              <div class="another 1">1. another div 1</div>
              <div class="another 2">1. another div 2</div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="span4">
            <div class="listagem-item">
              <a href="https://test.com/3-test" class="produto-sobrepor" title="TEST 3">3RD ELEMENT</a>
              <div class="another 1">2. another div 1</div>
              <div class="another 2">2. another div 2</div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="span4">
            <div class="listagem-item">
              <a href="https://test.com/1-test" class="produto-sobrepor" title="TEST 1">1st ELEMENT</a>
              <div class="another 1">3. another div 1</div>
              <div class="another 2">3. another div 2</div>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for reply!! The items are already inside. So I tried the 1st code but it works only at the first element, and also ignores (but this error i was getting before) 2 another elements before the replaced element. Any Idea of why? I attach the full code to question. thanks again!!

Comment: @GabrielaWolff Hi, now that you've attached the full code can you please also show what your expected result will using the full HTML code that you provided?

Comment: Do you also want the content `<div class="another 1">another div 1</div>` to also move with the `<a>` tag? Or should each content div remain where they originally are?

Comment: Yes, I do. They match with each A.

Comment: @GabrielaWolff I've edited my answer, is that what you're after?

Comment: Thank you so much @NickParsons!! That's exactly what I need! I couldn’t reach it without your help, and I really appreciate everything you’ve done. I don't even think about `.append().`

(Btw, the "3.,2.,1."(numerals, just the text) in your answer are out of order/doesn't match with urls. Doesn't makes any difference in code, but maybe can confuse any future reader. )

Thank you again!!